# how to type special characters in wijesekara layout ?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-method

I have used wijesekara layout with windows xp. at there i could use alt+num to type the keys that are not in the keyboard. but now in ubuntu wijesekara layout it seems that this doesn't work. how can i type speciall characters those have to be written in normally by pressing alt and entering a number?

Answer (score 0):

By using the [numeric code point](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#ctrlshiftu) feature. Basicially replace **Alt** with **Ctrl+Shift+U**.